# Dynamically add kendo grid inside panel of kendo panelbar in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI in my Java JSP application.

I am able to load the panel bar dynamically but now i want to insert the grid into one of the panels when user clicks that panel. I got the select/expand event to catch that action but I am not sure how to insert the Grid there.

Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

```
function createAttendancePanel(){

$("#attendance-details").kendoPanelBar({ 
        expandMode: "multiple",
        select: selectAttndPanel
        });
    var attendancePanelBar = $("#attendance-details").kendoPanelBar().data("kendoPanelBar");

attendancePanelBar.append({text: "Absence This Year", id:"item1"}, attendancePanelBar.select());
};
```

This function is called when I select a particular element after the page is loaded.

Now when the panel with text "Absence this Year" is expanded or selected I want to add the grid into this panel.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, in case some one is looking for it:

First append the panel with "content" that has the div element

panelbar.append(

```
    {
        text: "<b>Item 2</b>",
        encoded: false,                                 
        content: "<div id='grid'></div>"                
    }
);
```

Now, convert that div into the grid.

var grid= $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: dataSource,
      scrollable: false,
      editable : true,
      navigatable: true,
      toolbar:  ["save","cancel", "create"],
      columns: ["Id", "Name", "Position"]
    }).data("kendoGrid");